# can't get request from url parameter in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have send parameter like this

```
$this->redirect(array(
    'controller' => 'tools',
    'action' => 'index',
    'myArgument' => 12
));
```

When I retrieve this parameter like that

```
$this->request['myArgument'];
```

It gives me a null value, why?

Comment: $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'tools', 'action' => 'index',12))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your redirect url like as

```
/tools/index/myArgument:12
```

Retrieve this parameter like that

```
$this->request['named']['myArgument'];
```

> Output :
>
> 12

Also can debug your url as

```
var_dump($this->request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write in your controller

```
$this->request->params['myArgument'];
```

or you can print the request like

```
pr($this->request);
```